# How to use awk with multivalue delimiter

Tags: linux, shell, unix

How I can use is `awk` delimiter which contains multivalue: "#@$"

I have file like this: Test1#@$Test2#@$Test3#@$Test4
I need to extract 'Test2'. 
After I execute this command: `awk -F "#@$" '{print $2}'`, nothing is displayed>

And after that `awk -F "#@$" '{print $1}'` i get full line

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that the field separator `FS` is considered to be a regular expression. The <dollar>-character (`$`) has a special meaning in regular expressions as it represents an anchor for the end-of-the-line. The solution is to escape it twice as the <backslash>-escapes are interpreted twice; once in lexical processing of the string and once in processing the regular expression:

```
awk -F '#@\\$' '{print $1}'
```

---

> An **extended regular expression** can be used to separate fields by assigning a string containing the expression to the built-in variable `FS`, either directly or as a consequence of using the `-F` sepstring option. The default value of the `FS` variable shall be a single <space>. The following describes `FS` behaviour:
>
> 1. If `FS` is a null string, the behaviour is unspecified.
> 2. If `FS` is a single character:
>
>    - If `FS` is <space>, skip leading and trailing  <blank> and  <newline> characters; fields shall be delimited by sets of one or more  <blank> or  <newline> characters.
>    - Otherwise, if `FS` is any other character `c`, fields shall be delimited by every single occurrence of `c`.
> 3. **Otherwise, the string value of `FS` shall be considered to be an *extended regular expression*. Each occurrence of a sequence matching the extended regular expression shall delimit fields.**
>
> **<sub>source: [POSIX awk standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)</sub>**

---

> A <dollar-sign> (`$`) outside a bracket expression shall anchor the expression or subexpression it ends to the end of a string; such an expression or subexpression can match only a sequence ending at the last character of a string. For example, the EREs `ef$` and `(ef$)` match `ef` in the string `abcdef`, but fail to match in the string `cdefab`, and the ERE `e$f` is valid, but can never match because the `f` prevents the expression `e$` from matching ending at the last character.
>
> **<sub>source: [POSIX Extended Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04)</sub>**

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap $ in brackets [] to remove its special significance

```
> cat t1
Test1#@$Test2#@$Test3#@$Test4
> awk -F '#@[$]' '{print $2}' t1
Test2
>
```